# cyanogenmod lockscreen music controls

Tags: android, lockscreen, cyanogenmod, android-icons

I am looking for the png's of the music controls that appear on the lockscreen of CyanogenMOD roms, can anybody help me?
I was also looking for the source code of those controls, but couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Cyanogen source code can be found at their [github repo](https://github.com/cyanogenmod).

You should be able to find what you're looking for (if I understood your question) at: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Music

Comment: Thanks! I did look through the source code but somehow I missed it...Thank you

Comment: I don't think that their music app is implementing the lockscreen support feature